# Query Wordpress custom post by multiple conditions

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

Can anybody help me query custom post in WordPress?
I want to query multiple conditions:

```
if(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'nt_status', true) == "for-sale" && get_post_meta($post->ID, "nt_wlasnosc", true)!= "udział" && get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'nt_plot_size', true) <= "85" && get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'nt_listprice', true)/get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'nt_plot_size', true) <= "4847.40" && has_term( 'mieszkanie', 'propertytype' ) && has_term( 'poznan', 'location' )) :?>
        return true
   <?php endif; ?>

   <?php if(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'nt_status', true) == "for-sale" && get_post_meta($post->ID, "nt_wlasnosc", true)!= "udział" && get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'nt_plot_size', true) <= "85" && get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'nt_listprice', true)/get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'nt_plot_size', true) <= "4126.68" && has_term( 'mieszkanie', 'propertytype' ) && has_term( 'powiat-poznanski', 'location' )) :?>
        return true
   <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'nt_status', true) == "for-sale" && get_post_meta($post->ID, "nt_wlasnosc", true)!= "udział" && get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'nt_plot_size', true) <= "110" && get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'nt_listprice', true)/get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'nt_plot_size', true) <= "4847.40" && has_term( 'dom', 'propertytype' ) && has_term( 'poznan', 'location' )) :?>
        return true
   <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'nt_status', true) == "for-sale" && get_post_meta($post->ID, "nt_wlasnosc", true)!= "udział" && get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'nt_plot_size', true) <= "110" && get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'nt_listprice', true)/get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'nt_plot_size', true) <= "4126.68" && has_term( 'mieszkanie', 'propertytype' ) && has_term( 'powiat-poznanski', 'location' )) :?>
        return true
   <?php endif; ?>

   <?php if(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'nt_status', true) == "pierwotny" && get_post_meta($post->ID, "nt_wlasnosc", true)!= "udział" && get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'nt_plot_size', true) <= "85" && get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'nt_listprice', true)/get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'nt_plot_size', true) <= "5924,60" && has_term( 'mieszkanie', 'propertytype' ) && has_term( 'poznan', 'location' )) :?>
        return true
   <?php endif; ?>

   <?php if(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'nt_status', true) == "pierwotny" && get_post_meta($post->ID, "nt_wlasnosc", true)!= "udział" && get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'nt_plot_size', true) <= "85" && get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'nt_listprice', true)/get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'nt_plot_size', true) <= "5043,72" && has_term( 'mieszkanie', 'propertytype' ) && has_term( 'powiat-poznanski', 'location' )) :?>
        return true
   <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'nt_status', true) == "pierwotny" && get_post_meta($post->ID, "nt_wlasnosc", true)!= "udział" && get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'nt_plot_size', true) <= "110" && get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'nt_listprice', true)/get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'nt_plot_size', true) <= "5924,60" && has_term( 'dom', 'propertytype' ) && has_term( 'poznan', 'location' )) :?>
        return true
   <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'nt_status', true) == "pierwotny" && get_post_meta($post->ID, "nt_wlasnosc", true)!= "udział" && get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'nt_plot_size', true) <= "110" && get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'nt_listprice', true)/get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'nt_plot_size', true) <= "5043,72" && has_term( 'dom', 'propertytype' ) && has_term( 'powiat-poznanski', 'location' )) :?>
        return true
   <?php endif; ?>
```

I have template and know that it can be done by `$args['meta_query'][] = array( with AND & OR relative)` but maybe someone have simpler solution?

Comment: `meta_query` is your best option here, and probably only option, except if you want to run a custom SQL query which you should not really do

Answer (score 0):

Is there any option to use this conditions to store to property meta information? Something like: if condition true -> property meta = 1

Something like this:

```
if(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'nt_status', true) == "for-sale" && get_post_meta($post->ID, "nt_wlasnosc", true)!= "udział") :?>
get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'nt_mdm', true) = 1
<?php endif; ?>
```

I don't know how can I store this info to query?

get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'nt_mdm', true) = 1   <- this doesn't work

And then simple query:

```
$args['meta_query'][] = array(
    'key' => 'nt_mdm',
    'value' => 1,
    'compare' => 'IN'
);
```